# The score in my game will not reset back to zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my SpriteKit game, the score does not reset back to zero unless the app is exited completely. When you go to the game menu, and click play again, the score from the previous game continues. The method I use in updating my score is:

```
if (person1.position.y < obstacle1Node.position.y) {
    staticScore++;
    scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)staticScore];
}
```

The score is updated each time an obstacle node passes the person node. When exiting the game play scene, the code I use is:

```
scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
scoreNumber = 0;

SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.01];

[self runAction:wait completion:^{
    GameMenu *gameMenu = [GameMenu sceneWithSize:self.frame.size];
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1.0];
    [self.view presentScene:gameMenu transition:transition];
    [self removeAllActions];
    [self removeAllChildren];
}];
```

This code is used for the home and restart buttons. I am not quite sure why the score does not reset to zero. Previously, before I implemented a complex Game Over menu, the score would reset back to zero when the game would go to another scene and then back to the GamePlay scene. `scoreNumber` is declared as an `NSInteger`. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Where do you declare `staticScore` and what's the difference between `staticScore` and `scoreNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this `scoreNumber = 0;`. You are incrementing `staticScore` for score update and increase but you are setting `scoreNumber = 0` when you are exiting the play scene. You need to do `staticScore = 0` for resetting the score.